# Start/stop service script like Ubuntu for RedHat

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, scripting, services

Is there a .sh script that manages starting and stopping the service like Debian/Ubuntu but for Red Hat/Fedora? Looking to place it into the file running some software.

Comment: A systemd service file is how processes and daemons are managed in those distros.

Comment: RHEL7, I assume?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not writing your own software but want to start/stop existing service, than like @jasonwryan wrote, RHEL/Fedora are using systemd. The command for handling services is systemctl.

```
systemctl start/stop/restart servicename
```

If you want to list the installed services, use:

```
systemctl list-units
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at `/etc/rc.d/init.d`

You'll have a few services there to examine.  You can also test the service script by checking the status of your net work with:

```
$ sudo service network status
```

Comment: RedHat and Fedora use systemd now...

Comment: I thought I had downloaded and explored the latest version of Fedora (the free Red Hat supported version), version Fedora 20.  Which version are you running (the Fedora counterpart)?

Comment: I don't use Fedora, but they moved to it [in 2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd#Adoption)...